# AttributeError: type object 'database' has no attribute 'initialize'

Tags: python, mongodb

```sh
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\fullstack\terminal\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/terminal/mongo1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/terminal/mongo1.py", line 5, in <module>
    database.initialize()
AttributeError: type object 'database' has no attribute 'initialize'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

its giving me this error after running the below code please help im still new in python programming I have checked but I don't see where I dii it wrong!

```
class database(object):
    uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    database = None


@staticmethod
def initialize():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(database.uri)
    database.database = client["samaz"]



@staticmethod
def insert(collection, data):
    database.database[collection].insert(data)


@staticmethod
def find(collection, query):
    return database.database[collection].find(query)


@staticmethod
def find_one(collection, query):
   return database.database[collection].find_one(query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that most of the class definition is not indented as it should be. Remember that in python indentation is crucial, and is why braces {} are not required. This works for me error-free:

```
class database(object):
    uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    database = None


    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(database.uri)
        database.database = client["samaz"]



    @staticmethod
    def insert(collection, data):
        database.database[collection].insert(data)


    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query):
        return database.database[collection].find(query)


    @staticmethod
    def find_one(collection, query):
       return database.database[collection].find_one(query)

x = database()
print(x)
```

Also your traceback shows you using Python 3.x, in which inheriting from object is now done by default so no need to do that.

Also see Edvard's post. This will only stop you getting a traceback but he raises an important point about your class design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your methods inside the class, like so:

```py
class Database:
    uri = ...

    def  __init__(self):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.uri)
        self.database = self.client["samaz"]
```

To me it also looks like you want to have those other methods inside the class,
without @staticmethod decorator. It is used for methods that don't use class nor instance itself, basically using current class only as namespace.